# Set prototype of constructor function without using Object.setPrototypeOf?

Tags: javascript

I have been working on an ORM-like method of handling my models in a Node.JS app, and I am satisfied with how it works; however, I am wondering if there is a better way to handle resetting the prototype of a constructor function.

The behavior I want is something like this:

```js
function Person(data) {
  for (const key in data) {
    this[key] = data[key]
  }
}

// setting methods and so on here

Person.findAll() // returns a list of all persons from the db
Person.findOne(id) // returns a person at that ID

const self = new Person(data) // creating a person object
self.save() // saves that object in the db
self.update(data) // updates person object
self.addFriend(id) // creates a record adding the given id as a friend
```

There are methods on the constructor `Person` that have access to all `Person` records, while each instance of `Person` has methods that affect just that one record. I'm managing this like so:

```js
const utils = (tablename) => ({
  findAll: () => dbHandler(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename}`),
  findOne: id => dbHandler(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename} WHERE id = $1`, [id]),
  // etc
})

Object.setPrototypeOf(Person, utils('people'));
```

`.setPrototypeOf` isn't the *best* method to use; it's not particularly performant. I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle a use case like this -- for example, is there anything in the es6 class spec that would handle this? (Extending classes isn't quite what I'm looking for; the distinction between `Person.findAll()` and `self.update(data)` is important to me, and I would like the util methods to be on the constructor itself.)

Edit: Shoutout to Bergi below for the solution ("just use `Object.assign`")... here's a little demo:

```js
const dbHandler = (string, arr) => console.log(string, arr)

function Person(data) {
  for (const key in data) {
    this[key] = data[key]
  }
}

const utils = (tablename) => ({
  findAll: () => dbHandler(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename}`),
  findOne: id => dbHandler(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename} WHERE id = $1`, [id]),
  // etc
})

Object.assign(Person, utils('people'));

Person.prototype.save = function() {
  console.log(`Saving person with data ${JSON.stringify(this)} to a totally real database`)
}

Person.findAll()
Person.findOne(1)

const self = new Person({
  name: 'j',
  class: 'wizard'
})
self.save()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to involve any inheritance here (and setting the prototype of a constructor function so that it no longer inherits from `Function.prototype` is really weird). Just assign the static methods as properties of the `Person` constructor object:

```
Object.assign(Person, utils('people'));
```

This has the same effect as

```
function createUtils(obj, tablename) {
  obj.findAll = () => dbHandler(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename}`);
  obj.findOne = id => dbHandler(`SELECT * FROM ${tablename} WHERE id = $1`, [id]);
  // etc
}
createUtils(Person, 'people');
```

Comment: *facepalm* You are totally right, I have been using this pattern for a while and don't recall why I didn't just try `Object.assign` the first time around. I guess I didn't think it would work with a function, but `Object.setPrototypeOf` is just fine... oh well. That has the desired behavior. Thank you!